# Fetch own mobile number in android

Tags: android

Suppose my phone no is 9-112-345-678, I try given code

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNo = mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
```

but its not giving any output when i install same application in samsung fit 2.2.1 O.S.

I also gave necessary permission

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

Comment: see [this][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/get-phone-number-problem

Answer (score 1):

It depends on SIM card. If your SIM card contains it, then **getLine1Number** would return you, otherwise its *empty*. You can verify this by going into:

> Settings->About Phone->Status->My phone number

On the other hand, take any old nokia/sony-ericsson phone, put your sim in it, and browse to an option to Insert/Edit your sim number. I know, i had to do this to fix this issue with my phone number.

Comment: BUt i want to do this thing in newer version phones so can u provide any suggessions for that

Comment: At the moment, if your SIM card doesn't have its number stored in it, then you are out of luck. Though Android is considering this (change sim number) feature to add, but don't know when or in which release it will be provided

Comment: alternatively, borrow an iPhone, insert your sim, and browse to the option to alter your sim-number