# Obtaining Phone number

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get the user's phone number but the problem is that I am getting null response 
based on my research so far we can get the same by using the object of TelePhony Manager and calling function getLine1Number()

but I am not getting any response,somebody suggested that this is because the service provider is not providing the same in my country I am in India but for blackberry it's providing the phone number so what could be the possible problem please suggest my whole algo depends on this.

Comment: have you check ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853220/retrieve-incoming-calls-phone-number-in-android

Comment: what do you mean when you say, for blackberry its providing?

Comment: check my erlier answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534534/android-reading-device-phone-number-throws-nullpointerexception/11534625#11534625

Comment: Thanks jeet  your answer is really helpful you mean to say it's unavailable in India but I can get that for the Brazilian users ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

to your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: I am using this I am trying to obtain user's own phone number

Comment: Retrieving the device's associated phone number isn't an exact art - some sim cards do not readily provide it how Android wants it, so you may be having issues obtaining it because of this

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using

`String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);`

If you have already used this, I will recommend that you elaborate your question in a more specific way.

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your android manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
</uses-permission>
```

use following code to get number

```
number = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
```