# Installation of plugin in phonegap app

Tags: android, cordova

I want to create an phonegap app using [this plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin). I have done this steps to create and add plugin :

1:I am creatin this app using phonegap cli :-

```
phonegap create GetPhone --id "com.phone" --name "GetPhoneApp"
```

2: Going into the project and buid

```
cd GetPhone
phonegap local build android
```

3:Installing plugin

```
phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin
```

4:moving telephonenumber.js to www folder

5: adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="telephonenumber.js"></script>
```

into index.html then added below ondeviceready :-

```
var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/telephonenumber");
        telephoneNumber.get(function(result) {
        alert("result = " + result);
        }, function(error) {
        alert("error = " + error.code);
        });
```

6: Added

```
<plugin name="TelephoneNumber" value="com.simonmacdonald.cordova.plugins.TelephoneNumber"/>
```

into config.xml in www directory.

7: Build

```
phonegap local build android
```

8: Uploaded into build.phonegap.com and created .apk file.

Then when i am running this app on android device it does not alert anything. Is there any wrong step i have taken. I dont know much more about phone gap. After googling i have created this. I have seen [this tutorial](http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2012/12/how-to-get-devices-phone-number-using.html) also to add this plugin. When i am build it locally it does not show any error. But it is also not running.

Please help me find the error.

Comment: If you change `console.log` to `alert` in your code does that give you an alert?

Comment: No there is no alert. I think i am mistaking somewhere. Is my process is wright .........

Comment: Please help me ... I need a plugin to get phone number.

Comment: which telephone no u get

Comment: It is showing "error = undefined". I need the phone number of current device.

Comment: What version of Cordova are you using? Have you tried building directly, without build.phonegap.com?

Comment: Also post your log output, I have a feeling you're asking for the number too early and getting a bunch of undefined errors in the log. Please look inside `adb logcat`.

Comment: I am new in developing phonegap. How can i check cordova version. Is there any other way to build? I have also run it using "phonegap local run -V android" ...

Comment: I am using phonegap 3.2.0

Comment: Is my question is not clear?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the step 5 code into a 'deviceready' event listener?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43762/discussion-between-friends-of-everyone-and-soulseekah)

Comment: @soulseekah Yes i have also tried. But it is showing the "error" alert..

Comment: Many many thanx to all of you who have helped me a lot. Now i think i have to use my backup option to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I would suggest you get acquainted with standard tools, especially [`adb`](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html). These will allow you to provide more information, find out what really is going on.

Skimming through the [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/index.html) is also helpful, so you can be sure you know what you're doing and why you're doing it. Look at step-by-step debugging of Android code as well.

I would also encourage you to build a Cordova application from sources without using the fancy tools to get the hang of what goes where and how all the components come together. Your source tree is confusing and you seem to have used a mixture of Cordova 3.1 and Cordova 2.9, and even Phonegap? You only need to include `cordova.js` and your script (`js/script.js` in this case), nothing else at the moment.

Having said that, on to the major issue.

Your call to `get` returns an error. Why? Take a quick look at the source code of the plugin:

https://github.com/macdonst/TelephoneNumberPlugin/blob/master/src/com/simonmacdonald/cordova/plugins/TelephoneNumber.java

The plugin retrieves the [`TelephonyManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) and tries to call the [`getLine1Number`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()). And as you can see `result != null` is false which drops through to returning a `PluginResult.Status.ERROR`, which is why you get your error alert box.

This is the core issue at hand. `TelephonyManager` returning a `null` for your request. Why? After searching around you might stumble on:

- [Retrieve phone Number in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12278400/retrieve-phone-number-in-android)
- [TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing)
- [Reading device phone number throws NULLPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534534/android-reading-device-phone-number-throws-nullpointerexception)

So, navigate over to Settings > About Phone > Status on your device and look at the "My phone number" field. Is it "Unknown"? Tough luck then. My SIM doesn't store the number, so I got the same results as you did.

Another thing to note, is that at least on Android 4.4, the method returns an empty string `""` instead of a `null`, so when testing on my Android 2.3.7 device I got a `null` and thus got the error branch. But on my Android 4.4.2 device I got a `""` and got the success branch, but the number was empty, obviously.

You can set the number on the emulator by using [this pretty advanced guide](http://vrt-blog.snort.org/2013/04/changing-imei-provider-model-and-phone.html) if you'd like to try. So what can you do? Probably nothing by using the API, not even the Android system itself can get your number if it's not stored on the SIM card. Asking the user or sending an SMS to discover the number via a web service may be an option as well.

Comment: Thanx for replying. As you have told "SIM doesn't store the number" i have also seen on some SO question. So, there is a possibility in my code that can give device number or not. And i have also thinks about SMS Verification. This is my backup option. So i am not sure in this code that i will get device number. You mean i cant get phone number by any code?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. Again, if you navigate over to Settings > About Phone > Status on your device and look at the "My phone number" field and its "Unknown" or empty - then not even Android could get your phone. You'll have to solve the problem by other means.

Answer (score 1):

Step number 5 above will not work unless the code is called after the 'deviceready' event is triggered.

you will need some sort of call to know when the document is loaded, you can do either:

```
<body onload="onLoad()">
<script>
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
}
</script>
```

OR (w/ jquery):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', deviceReady, false);
}
</script>
```

and then create this function:

```
function deviceReady() {
    var telephoneNumber = cordova.require("cordova/plugin/telephonenumber");
    telephoneNumber.get(function(result) {
    alert("result = " + result);
    }, function(error) {
    alert("error = " + error.code);
    });
}
```

This will ensure that your document has loaded and that cordova is ready to call to.

Comment: Thanx for helping me. But i have already tried and also shared my code before. Which are http://www.4shared.com/zip/XTtY2Sso/GetPhone.html and http://www.4shared.com/zip/fOnDiB9Y/GetNumber.html. Could you take a look on this.