# getLine1Number() is not working

Tags: android

I want to get The SIM phone number using android but when I get The number the length is zero!
here is the code:

```
TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String s=mTelephonyMgr.getLine1Number();
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "The length is "+s.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

but it will Toast " The length is zero". When I print the number it will print nothing.
Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: do you have SIM inserted or you are testing it in Emulator ?

Comment: some SIM cards just don't provide that information

Comment: it is ok on the emulator but it is not ok on my phone.

Comment: `getLine1Number()` returns the phone number off the SIM card. Sometimes the phone number is on the SIM card, some times it isn't. And sometimes it is wrong. The only sure way to get the user's phone number is to ask him for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Get SIM Number**

```
 TelephonyManager telemamanger = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String getSimSerialNumber = telemamanger.getSimSerialNumber();
```

**Get Phone Number**

```
TelephonyManager tMgr =(TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
  mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

This Will Show you if applicable otherwie show [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725/).

Comment: it did not show my phone number -_-

Comment: what you want sim or phone number ?

Comment: I need phone Number

Answer (score 1):

Buddy it happens to me also , in the end i come to know  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134725/1218762)  solution

Comment: I've also seen this issue, it is highly SIM and device dependant. You can't guarantee that Android will be able to provide you the device phone number.