# How to get the mobile number from real device in android?

Tags: java, android

I have seen all most all posts regarding this issue but could not yet solved .I tried to get it from TelephonyManager.getVoiceMailNumber(),getLine1Number() but it will return as "null".

Please help me to solve it, if any other  way to get it.

Comment: your can get but not in every sim card. because some companies doesnt provide it..

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>``
```

Comment: Ya I have used it.More over I used to get IMEI no of emulator as well as sim no but tried to finding mobile number.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation `.getLine1Number()` "Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the **MSISDN** for a **GSM** phone. Return null if it is unavailable. "

Apparently `.getLine1Number()` reads this information from SIM card, so if the operator has set the MSISDN field it will return you its value and null if they did not set this field.

In your case probably your SIM card does not have this field populated by operator.

For More Info You can [Visit this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134725/1218762).

I got this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5134725/1218762).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Ok how can I check about MSISDN ?I went through the link which you provided and checked in my phone also Phone->about phone->status->my phone number shows "unknown".

Comment: @VilasmatiHanjagi so you can't get Mobile Number because sim doen't contain mobile number

Comment: Ok but we can get it once we have SIM card with valid  settings. Any way thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When reading this quiestion I started to look around for people with the same issue and found [this thread](http://androidforums.com/desire-support-troubleshooting/109948-phone-identity-question.html). It looks like not all operators/providers send the MSISDN number (Phone number) to your phone (As Segi before me has already pointed out).

If you go to Settings->About->"Phone identity" you might find out if you have a number on the SIM or not. In my case it says 'Unkown'.

Comment: We can conclude that now ,until unless mobile operators/ service providers sets the MSISDN to our SIM we can not obtain mobile number.