# Android How to get Phone number from the Dual sim phone

Tags: android, telephonymanager

Hello friends in my app i want to show user to their sim phone number but with in dual sim mobile is not give any type number i much googling but not get exact.please help meto get phone number from dual sim.
Note following is not working on dual sim to get number:

```
       String phonenumber = telephonymanager.getLine1Number();
```

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>  do u give this?

Answer (score 2):

`telephonymanager.getLine1Number()` does not guarantee to return the Sim number, as the phone number is not physically stored on all Sim cards.

A better alternative is to ask the user for the phone number once, and confirm the same by sending a message to that number.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing/5134725#5134725) is a better explanation for the same.