# How to Fetch Owner Mobile number from SMS Inbox/Sent

Tags: java, android, mobile, sms, owner

I have tried to retrieve all information from SMS Inbox/Outbox of my device. But my mobile number i.e. Sender's mobile number does not seem to be stored. I am trying to get this number so that I can capture mobile number from the OUTBOX and allow user to use it to register on my App, considering it to be near accurate mobile number that the user is using on the device. So that they don't have to type the mobile in my app for registration.

Please let me know if there is any way to find mobile number from the SMS INBOX/SENT

Code here:

```
public void readSMS (Activity MainActivity) 
{
    Uri inSMSUri = Uri.parse ("content://sms/inbox");
    System.out.println ( "the URI :: " + inSMSUri);

    Cursor c = MainActivity.getContentResolver().query(inSMSUri, null, null, null, "date desc");
    if (c!= null) 
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder ();
        while (c.moveToNext ()) {
            System.out.println ("content:" + c.getString (c.getColumnIndex ("body")));

            for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++)
            {
                System.out.println("SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: "+c.getColumnName(i) + 
                " c.getString(i):: "+c.getString(i));
            }

        }
        c.close ();


        Uri outSMSUri = Uri.parse ("content://sms/sent");

        c = MainActivity.getContentResolver().query(outSMSUri, null, null, null, "date desc");
        if (c!= null) 
        {

            while (c.moveToNext ()) {
                System.out.println ("content:" + c.getString (c.getColumnIndex ("body")));

                for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++)
                {
                    System.out.println("SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: "+c.getColumnName(i) + 
                    " c.getString(i):: "+c.getString(i));
                }

            }

        }

    }
}
```

But SENDER Mobile number column NOT found:

SMS INBOX is generating this output:

```
content:Hello! You are roaming on Vodafone Maharashtra

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: _id c.getString(i):: 9

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: thread_id c.getString(i):: 3

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: address c.getString(i):: VM-VDFONE

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: m_size c.getString(i):: 297

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: person c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: date c.getString(i):: 1381599923412

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: date_sent c.getString(i):: 1381599913000

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: protocol c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: read c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: status c.getString(i):: -1

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: type c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: reply_path_present c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: subject c.getString(i):: null

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: body c.getString(i):: Hello! You are roaming on Vodafone Maharashtra

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: service_center c.getString(i):: +919820005556

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: locked c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: sim_id c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: error_code c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: seen c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:INBOX: c getColumnName(i):: ipmsg_id c.getString(i):: 0

But SENDER Mobile number column NOT found:

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: _id c.getString(i):: 1783

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: thread_id c.getString(i):: 26

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: address c.getString(i):: 1909

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: m_size c.getString(i):: null

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: person c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: date c.getString(i):: 1394009796560

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: error_code c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: seen c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: ipmsg_id c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: m_size c.getString(i):: 21

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: person c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: date c.getString(i):: 1392004530098

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: date_sent c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: protocol c.getString(i):: null

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: read c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: status c.getString(i):: -1

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: type c.getString(i):: 2

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: reply_path_present c.getString(i):: null

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: subject c.getString(i):: null

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: body c.getString(i):: Take care

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: service_center c.getString(i):: null

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: locked c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: sim_id c.getString(i):: 1

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: error_code c.getString(i):: 0

SMS:SENT: c getColumnName(i):: ipmsg_id c.getString(i):: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following ways to get the mobile number:

1. TelephonyManager - Will not work for most of the numbers
       TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
       final String contactNumber = telephonyManager.getLine1Number();
2. AccountManager - Fetch number from accounts like WhatsApp and Telegram
   AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(context);
       Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();
       String contactNumber = null;
       if (accounts.length > 0) {
           for (Account acc : accounts) {
               if ("com.whatsapp".equals(acc.type)) {
                   if (!acc.name.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {
                       contactNumber = acc.name;
                   }
               }
               if (contactNumber == null && "org.telegram.messenger.account".equals(acc.type)) {
                   if (!acc.name.matches(".*[a-zA-Z]+.*")) {
                       contactNumber = acc.name;
                   }
               }
           }
       }
3. Integrate with Sms API like https://www.twilio.com/ 
   Ask user for number and send sms to the user's number with some authentication code. Either ask user to input the authentication code or the app can directly read the incoming message, parse the authentication code and validate.
   It might not work with full DND registered numbers from India.
4. Missed Call!!!
   Integrate with service like http://dial2verify.in/
   Ask user for phone number, make a call to dial2verify, it will return a phone number, ask user to give a missed call to the number. Once the missed call is received, dial2verify will make a call to your server with validate number details.

Comment: Hi Devashish, 1. I already implemented telephony manager, but not all simcards store the mobile number. 2. I have also implemented account manager code to get account name (whatsapp is no more storing the phone number in accounts) For 3 & 4 option : I am trying to get the phone number automatically & thereby avoiding to ask user to enter the whole 10 digit number. 3 & 4 will come post I fetch the number, but at this stage i am not getting method to fetch is automatically. asking user to input the mobile number is the last option.

Comment: @suren As of now there is no guaranteed method, that is the reason apps like whatsapp ask users to input the number. Using 1, 2 and 4 will help in saving the sms cost.

Answer (score -1):

`content://` has not worked well for me in the past. It seems that this changes based on the phone that the person is using.

I personally use this to get the phone number of the user:

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

ownerPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

If you NEED to do it that way though, I use:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://sms/");

Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(uri, null, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

String type = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("type"));
if (type.equals("2"))
{
     //An outgoing SMS was sent.
}
```

You can grab the phone number using `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(""))` (Although I forgot what column goes inside there for phone number. You can try a loop like you did above to see what values you receive.

Comment: hi MJ, I have done the loop (for(int i=0; i<c.getColumnCount();i++)), from this loop i could see there is no such column which is capturing the sender's mobile number. are you referring to these same columns to be looped, or something else.

also, the telephonyManager issue is, that all providers don't store mobile numbers in the SIM card. less 10% SIM cards will have this data. i am using this as an alternative method.

Comment: You're right, it looks like there is no universal way to grab the sender's phone number. Although, it is very easy to find the RECEIVERS phone number... but that does not help out much in your case. Here is a solution from another SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5134725/533049