# How to get the telephone number of the device

Tags: android, telephonymanager, phone-state-listener

I want to retrieve telephone number of the current Device. Now I cannot get the telephone number. I have added **READ_PHONE_STATE** permission in manifest. Here is my code

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) this.getSystemService(Context.
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code :

```
 TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Required Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

refer to link : [Programmatically obtain the phone number of the Android phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480288/programmatically-obtain-the-phone-number-of-the-android-phone)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have stored the phone number on the SIM card, and there´s no other way to get your "own number".

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing) link