# Is there an another way for to get my gsm mobile number?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

`TelephonyManager.getLine1Number` Method is returning `null`.

Because My Phone Number is unknown on my Android System.

Is there an another way or what must I do for true result?

Comment: Did you set the permission? (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

Comment: Yes, I set the permission. (android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TelephonyManager.getLine1Number() failing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5134398/telephonymanager-getline1number-failing)